# Reading integers from a file and keeping track of them, Assembly

Tags: assembly, integer, arm

I'm trying to write a program in ARMSIM that does the following:
Open a file named "integers.dat" and keep track of the following information:
the first integer value (i)
the second integer value (j)
the total number of integers in the file
the number of integers that are not i
the total number of integers less than j

So far I have the following from the ARMSIM guide

```
@@@ OPEN INPUT FILE, READ INTEGER FROM FILE, PRINT IT, CLOSE INPUT FILE 

.equ SWI_Open, 0x66         @open a file 
.equ SWI_Close,0x68         @close a file
.equ SWI_PrChr,0x00         @ Write an ASCII char to Stdout 
.equ SWI_PrStr, 0x69        @ Write a null-ending string 
.equ SWI_PrInt,0x6b         @ Write an Integer 
.equ SWI_RdInt,0x6c         @ Read an Integer from a file 
.equ Stdout, 1          @ Set output target to be Stdout 
.equ SWI_Exit, 0x11         @ Stop execution 
.global _start 
.text
_start:
@ print an initial message to the screen 
mov R0,#Stdout          @print an initial message 
ldr R1, =Message1       @ load address of Message1 label 
swi SWI_PrStr           @ display message to Stdout 

@ == Open an input file for reading =============================

@ if problems, print message to Stdout and exit 
ldr r0,=InFileName      @ set Name for input file 
mov r1,#0           @ mode is input 
swi SWI_Open            @ open file for input 
bcs InFileError         @ Check Carry-Bit (C): if= 1 then ERROR
@ Save the file handle in memory: 
ldr r1,=InputFileHandle         @ if OK, load input file handle 
str r0,[r1]                 @ save the file handle 

@ == Read integers until end of file =============================

RLoop: 
ldr r0,=InputFileHandle     @ load input file handle 
ldr r0,[r0] 
swi SWI_RdInt           @ read the integer into R0 
bcs EofReached          @ Check Carry-Bit (C): if= 1 then EOF reached 
@ print the integer to Stdout 
mov r1,r0           @ R1 = integer to print 
mov R0,#Stdout          @ target is Stdout 
swi SWI_PrInt 
mov R0,#Stdout          @ print new line 
ldr r1, =NL 
swi SWI_PrStr 
bal RLoop           @ keep reading till end of file

@ == End of file ===============================================

EofReached: 
mov R0, #Stdout         @ print last message 
ldr R1, =EndOfFileMsg 
swi SWI_PrStr

@ == Close a file ===============================================
ldr R0, =InFileHandle       @ get address of file handle 
ldr R0, [R0]            @ get value at address 
swi SWI_Close

Exit: 
swi SWI_Exit            @ stop executing 
InFileError: 
mov R0, #Stdout 
ldr R1, =FileOpenInpErrMsg 
swi SWI_PrStr 
bal Exit            @ give up, go to end 
.data 
.align
InFileHandle:       .skip       4 
InFileName:         .asciz      "whatever.txt" 
FileOpenInpErrMsg:  .asciz      "Failed to open input file \n" 
EndOfFileMsg:       .asciz      "End of file reached\n" 
ColonSpace:         .asciz": " 
NL:             .asciz      "\n "   @ new line 
Message1:       .asciz      "Hello World! \n" 
.end
```

When I run the code I get an error "unknown opcode or directive" for lines      11 through 18.

How do I modify this code to get the results I want?

Comment: You seem to be missing space after the `.equ` in the first few lines, but those are definitely not 11 through 18...

Comment: Thank you! I fixed that and now the only errors Im getting are "Undefined symbol InputFileHandle" rigth after '
ldr r1,=InputFileHandle ' and 'ldr r0,=InputFileHandle'

Comment: Well, "InputFileHandle" != "InFileHandle"